# Seeing rogue output on a basic apache stack

Tags: apache, apache2, bitnami

I am trying to get a simple apache stack running and came across something I have not seen before. This is an AWS instance running the Bitnami LAMP stack. If I create an incomplete html file as:

```
<h1>Something Here</h1>
```

Apache is prepending  to the response. E.g.

```
<head/><h1>Something Here</h1>
```

I am serving an angular2 app from this stack and loading of the component templates is failing since they are being seen as malformed. Does anyone know what apache setting or module might be doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PageSpeed is the one that's adding that `<head/>`. PageSpeed is enabled by default on the Bitnami LAMP Stack.

This is added by the default mod_pagespeed add_head filter. You can disable it adding the line below to `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/pagespeed.conf`:

`ModPagespeedDisableFilters add_head`

However, note that this filter is needed for many other filters which will only write contents in the element.

You can also disable PageSpeed as explained in the guide below to check that the header disappear:
https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/lamp/#how-to-disable-the-cache-in-the-server